# Django admin: Manually delete error-note

Tags: django, django-admin

is there a way to manually delete the error-note shown at the top of the page in the admin.
I got a User-Admin with the Profile as an Inline. It is easy to delete the form errors but I do not know how to delete the "global" error shown at the top of the page.

Comment: Delete how? Do you want to remove the markup which generates the error code, or are you looking to remove the error message from the non_field_errors array that is used by that markup?

Comment: I don't want to remove the markup which generates the error code, but the error message from non-field errors. But I have no idea how to get to them.